# Balls go through Zubats and other flying types?

Tags: pokemon-go

Sorry if this question has been answered before. I am a level 23 player and I have become pretty proficient at catching Pokémon. All except the (very common around here) zubats and occasionally other flying types: The Pokéball goes through them when I release it. Hard to describe. My question is, whether others have noted this or is this my problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Unless you're experiencing an extremely rare bug, I have not been able to find or reproduce balls going through Pokemon.

However, Zubat is notorious for having an extremely small hitbox:

```
CollisionRadiusM: 0.0535
CollisionHeightM: 0.0535
CollisionHeadRadiusM: 0.1605
```

It most likely is that your balls are just not hitting this target hitbox, which may have the semblance of a ball "going through" your Zubat and others.

You can also compare this to the hitbox of Pidgey:

```
CollisionRadiusM: 0.1344
CollisionHeightM: 0.252
CollisionHeadRadiusM: 0.126
```

---

Additionally, it may be a good idea to note that Flying Pokemon will tend to "wander" around the screen a bit more, causing their hitbox to be non-stationary, unlike their ground-type equivalents.

Comment: Also, due to the fact that the screen is 2d, if the ball is behind or in front of the Pokemon, it often looks like the ball "goes right through them".

Comment: I will take that response. Yeah, it might only look like they are going through instead of the moving hitbox. thanks for this.

Comment: The distance and (as you mentioned) the moving hitbox make it incredibly difficult to catch Zubat and Golbat especially. The fact that there is now this bug just makes me want to give up on Golbat altogether.

Comment: Golbats are absolutely the f*cking worse.  I hate Golbats.  Their hitboxes and "distance" is ridiculous I just don't bother.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know the code, but, I know that on slower phones (even slightly slower) you'll have to wait a couple of seconds before the game places their hitbox to be, well, hit.